# How do I solve "length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent" in spatial Autocorrelation (R)

Tags: r, statistics

I am doing  local spatial correlation using Local Moran's I Statistic using R programming language.
The code runs okay in finding neighbors, converting neighbors to a listw object but stops when it gets to running the global model
**Code**

```
setwd("H:/R")
library("sf")
library("sp")
library("spdep")
library("rgdal")
library("rgeos")
library("ggplot2")
library("tmap")
OA.Census<- readOGR(".","Kenya")

RC.neighbours <- poly2nb(OA.Census, queen = FALSE) #Rook's case neighbors
listw<- nb2listw(RC.neighbours, zero.policy =TRUE)  #Convert the neighbour data into a listw 
moran.test(OA.Census$Population,listw, zero.policy= TRUE)
```

**Error**

```
Error in moran.test(OA.Census$Population, listw, zero.policy = TRUE) : 
  OA.Census$Population is not a numeric vector
```

I coerced the column I was interested in, to a numeric Vector and the global model worked alright

```
Pop <- as.numeric(OA.Census$Population)
moran.test(Pop,listw, zero.policy= TRUE)
```

**Result**

```
Moran I test under randomisation

data:  Pop  

weights: listw  n reduced by no-neighbour observations
  

Moran I statistic standard deviate = 2.9727, p-value = 0.001476
alternative hypothesis: greater
sample estimates:
Moran I statistic       Expectation          Variance 
      0.227104264      -0.022222222       0.007034374
```

**However, when I then run local model, I get the dimnames error**

`moran<- moran.plot(Pop, listw =nb2listw(RC.neighbours,zero.policy= TRUE, style = "W"))'

**Error**

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning message:
In lag.listw(listw, x, zero.policy = zero.policy) : NAs in lagged values
```

How do I solve this problem, or is my data erroneous?
This is my data link[Data](https://github.com/vn-cheruiyot/Rdata/blob/main/Data.zip)

Comment: Would you mind providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it's possible to investigate what's going on? I see that you added a link to your data, but it would be much better to define some example data as code so that people can copy-paste your code and get to your problem directly.

Comment: If you have the data object, then using `dput(head(obj))` might helpful in paring that 2.5MB file down to a size that would be more in keeping withe the “minimal” part of MCVE directive.